# What is the proper way to build and call a specific version of solidity?

Tags: solc, compilation

I am getting the following error from `solc`:

```
Error: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.11-develop.2017.6.22+commit.68ef5810.Darwin.appleclang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.11;
^---------------------^
```

In order to build `solc`, I:

1. cloned the solidity repository,
2. ran `git  checkout v0.4.11` which successfully got the `tag/v0.4.11`. 3. completed the build process
3. made sure `solc` was in my path

   ```
   solc --version
   solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
   Version: 0.4.11-develop.2017.6.22+commit.68ef5810.Darwin.appleclang
   ```

So, that is the v0.4.11 release, but the version number has today's date in it. Is that the source of the error?

System is macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by RTFM. Mac users should install using Homebrew.

From [Installing Solidity](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages)

> ```
> brew update 
> brew upgrade
> brew tap ethereum/ethereum
> brew install solidity
> brew linkapps solidity
> ```
>
> If you need a specific version of Solidity you can install a Homebrew
>   formula directly from Github.

Comment: for ubuntu: sudo npm install -g solc

Comment: You can probably accept your own answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

> **To Install specific version of solidity, use :**

```
npm install -g solc@0.4
```

This will install solidity compiler 0.4.26 (latest on that version), globally.

or

```
npm install -g solc@0.5
```

Then

```
$ solcjs --version
> 0.4.26+commit.4563c3fc.Emscripten.clang
```

Comment: This is probably useful to some people but it's worth pointing out that this installs [`solcjs`](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#readme), not `solc`. The latter has quite a few nice features on the command line which solc-js is missing.

Comment: @maurelian as I know, `solcjs` also download the exact `solc` version - https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/master/wrapper.js#L331. So it can be handy

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew extract --version=0.8.17 solidity ethereum/ethereum
brew install solidity@0.8.17
```